# How can I make images disappear from a grid view on touch?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I have a grid view with various image views within it, and I want these images to disappear when touched.

How can I do this? How can I implement a touch listener for these grid view images?

Answer (score 2):

The ImageViews all are types of views and the layouts are ViewGroups. Any of these you can set the visibility to gone or removed.  So really you just neeed to implement onTouchListener event handler and then set visibility on the ImageViews.  So you might want to consider setting a whole layout to invisible as well if you want to hide them all at once.  You can do

```
LinearLayout myLinearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(myLinearLayoutId);
myLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE) // or to show again View.VISIBLE
```

in general

```
       view.setVisibility(View.GONE) or View.INVISIBLE
```

For tutorial on onTouchListener see: http://www.mybringback.com/tutorial-series/3279/android-the-basics-32-androids-ontouchlistener-and-motionevent/

Comment: but i want to do it on touch i dont want whole layout to disappear