# How to make bitmap invisible ontouch in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have a bitmap drawn on a canvas I want to setup an ontouch listener so
 that as soon as user touches the bitmap it becomes invisible.

Comment: post the code. post details about what you have tried?

Comment: See **your own** question's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11783374/how-can-i-make-images-disappear-from-a-grid-view-on-touch).

Comment: hey read before u all do -4 and mike gates u crazy u dont kno the difference between bitmaps and gridview ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this :

```
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(final View view, MotionEvent event) {

              final int action = event.getAction();

                     int x = event.getX()  // or getRawX();
                     int y = event.getY();

                    switch(action){
                          case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                   if (x >= xOfYourBitmap && x < (xOfYourBitmap +yourBitmap.getWidth())
                       && y >= yOfYourBitmap && y < (yOfYourBitmap + yourBitmap.getHeight())) {
        //You've pressed on your bitmap
    }
    break;
}
     }
```

Comment: what is the idofbitmap how can we get that ?